# Logstash - is Pull possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, vpn

We are trying to build up an ElasticSearch data collector. The ElasticSearch cluster should receive data from different servers. These servers are at other locations (and networks) than the ElasticSearch cluster. The clients are connected to the ElasticCluster via a one-way VPN connections.

As a first attempt we installed logstash on each client server to collect the data, filter it and send it to the ElasticCluster. So far it was no problem in a test environment. The problem is now that the LogStash from the client tries to establish a connection to ElasticSearch. However, this attempt is blocked by the firewall. It is however possible to open a connection from the ElasticCluster side to each client and receive the data. What we need is a way to get the data from LogStash so that we open a connection and pull the data from LogStash (PULL). Is there a way to do this without changing the VPN configuration?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question (i have not heard of way to enable what you want). We had a similar situation once due to limited connectivity, so we used a dedicated logstash server (in house) and rsync in order to sync the data we were interested in periodically over. You won't achieve live results this way though (you'll likely always be a few minutes behind).

Comment: I had such a similar question, I posted at DevOps: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/how-to-pull-beats-from-logstash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash push events, if your logstash instances can't initiate the connection with the elasticsearch nodes, you will need something in the middle or allow the traffic on the firewall/VPN.

For example, you can have a elasticsearch to where the logstash servers can push data and then another logstash in your main cluster environment where you will have a pipeline in which the input will be the elasticsearch in the middle, this way the data will be pulled from the elasticsearch.

edit:

As I've said in the comment, you need to have something like this image.

[image]

Here you have your servers sending data to a logstash instance, this logstash has an output to an elasticsearch instance, so it starts the connection pushing the data.

On your main cluster, where you have your elasticsearch cluster and an one way VPN that only can start a connection, you will have another logstash, this logstash will then have an input that will query the outside elasticsearch node, pulling the data.

In the logstash pipeline you can have a `elasticsearch` input, which queries a elasticsearch node, then send the data received to filters and outputs.

```
input {
    elasticsearch { the elasticsearch in the middle }
}
filter { 
    your filters 
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { your cluster nodes }
}
```

Is it clearly now?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Just to understand your answer correctly.
We install LogStash on our client server with different inputs and Lumberjack as output. On the main cluster environment we also install logstash with beats input and elasticsearch output.
Doesn't LogStash on the client side establish the connection in this case?
Or do you mean we should install a buffer database on every client that we fill locally with logstash and then fetch the data from there with a logStash instance on the main cluster?

Comment: Let me try to explain better.

You will send the data from your clients to a Logstash instance, this logstash will push this data to a elasticsearch instance that can receive push, as it will not initiate the connection, the connection will be initialized by logstash, it will be in its output.

Then, you will need another Logstash on the same netwokr of your main cluster that will then pull the data from this first elasticsearch, it will have an input that will query this elasticsearch.

I edited the answer to make it clearly.

Comment: That would roughly be the same as my second description. 
Logstash -> Buffer <- VPN <- Logstash -> ElasticSearch.  I already had this idea, but the data duplication for each client can become very large in some cases. The problem with your graphics is that the VPN is between the server and logstash, which would require many ES instances.
Internally we have discussed the problem and will probably write our own application for this problem now. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is there a "simpler" option when using FileBeat only, also through a one-way VPN (or one-way firewall...)?